# lotus notes outline element not shown when the application is opened

Tags: lotus-notes

There is an outline which contains many view displayed. The oultine is contained by a frame from a main frameset.

The users are complaining the fact that when they open the Lotus Client ( IBM Notes 9 ) and then open a Notes application, this outline is not displayed, in fact they see all the views like in the Designer.

If they close and (re)open the application the issue is gone, but still the issue appears again and again.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because you do not use the default frame- names in your frameset. Name them `NotesView` (for the view) and `NotesNavigator` for the outline, then this will most probably fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any chance to be a Client Lotus problem, and not a problem from the applications? I do use names for the view(s) and for the outline, but some users still complain about this issue.

Comment: I don't understand your answer... IF your Frames do NOT have the names "NotesView" and "NotesNavigator", then this problem MAY appear on SOME clients...

Comment: well, the applications are using the default frame - names in the frameset: NotesView for the vieew and NotesNavigator for the oultine. STILL, the issue persists.

Comment: OK, sorry, then this is not the reason for your problem